# Asp.Net Core with Docker - Duplicate 'Content' items were included

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-core

I have a problem when I would like to deploy my app with docker.
I'm using ASP.Net Core with docker.

This an error message:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(188,5):
>   error : Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes
>   'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either
>   remove these items from your project file, or set the
>   'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to
>   explicitly include them in your project file. For more information,
>   see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were:
>   'wwwroot/_version.txt'
>   [/Users/xxxxxx/Projects/api-test/TestApi/TestApi.csproj]

Here's my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1.1</TargetFramework>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
    <UserSecretsId>0a7aa24d-009c-4d0b-b0fd-e8be397b0784</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="CoreCompat.System.Drawing" Version="1.0.0-beta006" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Storage.V1" Version="1.1.0-beta01" />
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore" Version="1.5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="1.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="1.1.0-beta2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.7-m61" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorLight" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorLight.MVC" Version="1.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.5.0-dev-00817" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.4.1-dev-10155" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="2.2.0-dev-00721" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WkWrap.Core" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net" Version="0.15.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="SQL\" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\_version.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I think the problem is with a _version.txt file which is currently on the server (I can;t say that because I do not have an access) and It tries to duplicate it.

Would you mind to help me with that i

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325916/duplicate-content-items-were-included-the-net-sdk-includes-content-items-f

Answer (score 2):

The .NET SDK includes `Content` items from your project directory by default, so `wwwroot\_version.txt` is already present in your project. Your project file is then attempting to add it again, which causes the error.

You can use `Update` instead of `Include` to cause the existing content item to be updated, rather than including it twice.

So, you just have to change

```
<Content Include="wwwroot\_version.txt">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

to

```
<Content Update="wwwroot\_version.txt">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```