# Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included after migrate to .NET Standard?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Using VS 2017  15.4.0

Following James Montemagno "Upgrading to Xamarin.Forms to .NET Standard"

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-15-Upgrading-to-XamarinForms-to-NET-Standard?ocid=player

When trying to Clean/Build I am receiving the error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'EmbeddedResource' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'App.xaml'; 'MainPage.xaml'    App5.core   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   274

Any solution please?

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution...
Right click on the new .NET Standard project I have created "App5" and choose Edit App5.csproj
I have deleted this code from the file and the error gone.

```
      <ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="App.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
  </EmbeddedResource>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="MainPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This worked, but I wonder why. How can the project find the items when they are not listed in the project file at all?

Comment: It basically includes all the items inside the directory unless mentioned to exclude the specific item.

Answer (score 11):

I found various suggestions, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325916/duplicate-content-items-were-included-the-net-sdk-includes-content-items-f/45729335#45729335) was easily the best for me, both in simplicity and elegance:

- In Solution Explorer, enable "Show All Files". This displays all files in each folder, including those excluded from the project.

For each item listed in the error message:

- Exclude from project
- Include in project

Then

- In Solution Explorer, disable "Show All Files".

Comment: thanks! very strange, but error gone after I had excluded and included back my resource.resx

Answer (score 8):

My mistake was that I added embedded resource while simulator with app was running.

Soo... I had THIS added automatically inside .csproj file:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="**/*" />
```

Remove it, and then everything should be fine

Comment: Removing <EmbeddedResource Include="**/*" />
worked for me

Answer (score 6):

According to bugzilla of xamarin at some point you **were** required to insert to make it work with the new csproj format.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <!-- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55591 -->
    <None Remove="**\*.xaml" />

    <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.xaml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

[Source](https://github.com/onovotny/SampleXamFormsWithNetStandard/blob/fe90895f0201c9781c9ae4a3282f34011c4b74ca/XamFormsSample/XamFormsSample/XamFormsSample.csproj)

I would imagine that xamarin decided to add that to the default build targets now.

So to fix it you have to do the following:

- Open your shared .csproj file.
- **Remove all Itemgroups related to adding xaml pages and *.cs**
- clean + rebuild.

Comment: Replacing this part didn't solve the issue for me, AG70's solution worked for me.

Comment: "Remove all Itemgroups related to adding xaml pages"? that's exactly what he does too

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me in MS Visual Studio for Mac after I have added two font files as embedded resources.

These files were titled with the same prefix (Lora-Regular.ttf & Lora-Bold.ttf) and it looks like my IDE did handle this in a bad way.

Indeed, the following weird line was inserted in my .csproj file :

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="**/*" />
```

**All I did was removing this line and error disapeared.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean it manually with these steps:

- Close your VS
- remove bin and obj folders from iOS, Android and the Common (Your project name) folder.
- remove all content from the packages folder
- open a terminal, navigate to your projects folder and type `nuget locals all -clear`
- then type `nuget restore`

and finally open VS again and let me know if the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was in one file name. I used underscore (_) in the filename. I was working with file name AppResource.zh_cn.resx. May be it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

for me unloading and reloading project again worked!