# How to migrate Xamarin.Forms shared project in to .NetStandard project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms Shared project (not PCL) application and want to migrate to .NetStandard project. I checked in online, but not get any reference. I welcomes your hints

Thanks,

Comment: I recommend to create a new blank netStandard project and then copy paste all your files one by one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a new .NET Standard Project in the same Folder as your old
   shared project and than just add all files to the new project using
   Drag and Drop from SolutionExplorer in Visual Studio.
2. Add require packages
3. Replace your platform specific code

Like

```
 #if __MOBILE__
// Xamarin iOS or Android-specific code
#endif

//OR

#if __IOS__
// iOS-specific code
#endif
```

With

```
if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)//TargetIdiom.Tablet OR what ever you want
{
 -----
}
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)//OR Device.Android
{
 -----
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well, just needed to remove some duplicated embedded resources, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748950/duplicate-embeddedresource-items-were-included-after-migrate-to-net-standard