# Why is my project building with an unknown Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, modelbinders

So, my code seems to be compiling without errors when it should not compile.

Here, this project has no NuGet packages for AspNetCore.Mvc and hence this should not compile but still it does.

Notice, the `ModleBinder` is in white color which means it does not recognize this type - still it is compiling.
In another console app of the same VS this behaves fine.

I am using VS 2017 15.4

[image]

Some of the things I have already done

- restarted VS many times
- Deleted the .vs folder
- Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution
- deleted vs folder and restarted the computer

Comment: What does the tooltip say when you hover over `ModelBinder`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't trust syntax highlighting as an indication that references are, or aren't, available in the project.  Are you building or rebuilding the solution?

Comment: Did you try restarting your PC?

Comment: It happened to me that I opened a solution where a referenced assembly was missing. Visual Sudio silently remapped it to the DLL in the bin/Debug folder. Inspect the references. There might still be a reference living there.

Comment: restarted and rebuild the solution - same problem.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, did you have the syntax highlighting working at that point ?

Comment: Yes. I only noticed by accident that my references were pointing to the wrong place (my referenced library had moved).

Comment: If you're using Resharper, it has its own mechanism for warnings and syntax highlighting and such. Sometimes that gets out of sync, and you need to clear its caches.

Comment: Check your `bin` folder. It's likely that a copy of the referenced library was moved there in a previous build and hasn't been cleaned up.

Comment: Not using resharper and bin folder also does not have this library.

Comment: And what is the contents of csproj file? Nothing of interest there?

Comment: No, nothing special in .csproj file. So, in this very project the VS is not validating any type. Even if I write xxxxx as the type I get no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found the root cause.

The root cause of the mentioned issue is this line in the .csproj file

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

I had to add this line to avoid [another error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325916/duplicate-content-items-were-included-the-net-sdk-includes-content-items-f). But it seems this was not the right thing to solve this problem.
Instead [this seems to be right fix](http://jameschambers.com/2017/11/duplicate-compile-items-included/) for my original problem.