Bootstrap dropdown not working when blazor app is published
I have a blazor server-side app and I have the following component:
<div class="card-tools">
    <div class="btn-group text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" @onclick='() => {ItemClick("1");}'>Item 1</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" @onclick='() => {ItemClick("2");}'>Item 2</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" @onclick='() => {ItemClick("3");}'>Item 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnItemClicked { get; set; }

    private void ItemClick(string condition)
    {
        OnItemClicked.InvokeAsync(condition);  
    }
}

I also include jquery 3.6 and bootstrap 4.6 in the _Host.chtml.
When I run the app in VS, the dropdown is displayed as expected. However, when I publish the app, the dropdown is not being displayed.
What could be wrong?

Solved it using this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45729335/4264597

Voted to close this answer as the post owner solved his/her question by referencing: Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default.
